# Qemu is not configured correctly when custom machine is added

Tags: c, linux, embedded, qemu

I have been trying to develop a custom machine in **QEMU** : **STM32F407**. I have written initial script to add the machine name to the list of machines supported in QEMU when we do `-machine help` with  machine description like defining **SRAM**, **cpu-type** etc.  I have added the file in the path `~/qemu/hw/arm` as `stm32f407ve_scu.c`

I have also added the line `obj-$(CONFIG_STM32F407VE_SCU) += stm32f407ve_scu.o` in **makefile.objs** file.

The .c file has the below code :

```
struct stm32f407ve_scu {
    DeviceState *soc;
    struct arm_boot_info boot_info;

};

static void stm32f407ve_scu_init(MachineState *machine) { //create a space for the machine kernel
    struct stm32f407ve_scu *s =g_new0(struct stm32f407ve_scu, 1);

    if (!machine->kernel_filename){
        fprintf(stderr," Guest image is missing (use -kernel)\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    s->soc = qdev_create(NULL, "stm32f407-soc");
    qdev_prop_set_string (s->soc, "cpu-type", ARM_CPU_TYPE_NAME("cortex-m4")); // assign cortex-m4 as the processor
    object_property_set_bool(OBJECT(s->soc), true, "realized", &error_fatal);

    MemoryRegion *sram =g_new(MemoryRegion,1); //creates new memory region
    memory_region_init_ram(sram, NULL, "scu.sram", 1024 * 1024 * 128, &error_fatal); // ram area defined with size
    vmstate_register_ram_global(sram);

    //loads kernel of maximum size 2MB
    armv7m_load_kernel(ARM_CPU(first_cpu), machine->kernel_filename, 2 * 1024 * 1024);      

}
static void stm32f407ve_scu_machine_init(MachineClass *mc) //defines the machine init struct and description
{
    mc->desc = "STM32F407 board with RAM";
    mc->init = stm32f407ve_scu_init;
}
DEFINE_MACHINE("stm32f407ve_scu", stm32f407ve_scu_machine_init) //machine is defined with initialization clas
```

When I try to configure and make **QEMU** , I get no error but the `stm32f407ve_scu.o` and `stm32f407ve_scu.d` are not generated.

Why are the .o and .d files are not being generated? But when I see other .c files, they have been generated into .o and .c .

What am I missing here? I added all the header files as like other files and used the same syntax to write my machine description.

Comment: Please show the code and/or state the errors. Please don't use links to images. The text is missing from the question. The text on the picture is too small for some people to read. The text on the image cannot be indexed by search engines for future visitors. Also see [Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/608639)

Comment: I have actually added the image not a link , I dont know why it is showing error.  I will update. Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using `obj-$(CONFIG_STM32F407VE_SCU) += stm32f407ve_scu.o`, you need to enable `CONFIG_STM32F407VE_SCU` somewhere to build this file. This can be done in the `configure` file or editing `default-configs/arm-softmmu.mak` and adding `CONFIG_STM32F407VE_SCU=y`.

If you only need to build this extra file, you could just edit `Makefile.objs` like that:

```
obj-$(CONFIG_ARM_V7M) += armv7m.o stm32f407ve_scu.o
```

As you're using ARMv7m (Cortex M4), your file will be built (`CONFIG_ARM_V7M` will be equal to `y`)

Comment: Both obj-y and obj-$(CONFIG_ARM_V7M) += armv7m.o stm32f407ve_scu.o worked thank you.  Without adding CONFIG_STM32F407VE_SCU=y  in the .mak file obj-y worked , does that mean it takes any default value? that is CONFIG_ARM_V7M?  And what is the difference between adding CONFIG_ARM_V7M and custom name?

Comment: Yes, `CONFIG_ARM_V7M` is enabled by default when you build QEMU with arm-softmmu support.